# Flask from windows console python -c "from app import app; app.run(debug=True)"

Tags: python, flask

Running Flask in Windows, instead of invoke `C:>python run.py` where `run.py` is

```
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

I've tried

```
C:\python -c "from app import app; app.run(debug=True)"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Argument expected for the -c option
usage: D:\Dev\Flask\microblog\venv\Scripts\python.exe [option] ... [-c cmd | -m
mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.
```

But running `C:\python -c "from app import app; app.run()"` is Ok

How can I solve this silly question?

Answer (score 1):

You can't without fiddling with werkzeugs's source. What is happening is that the debug flag enables the reloader, which handles the way the process runs (and restarts) and it does not understand the -c argument for the python interpreter.